# Concatenate values from multiple rows from same field, aggregating

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, listagg

I have a dataset with names in one columns along with several other columns. I would like to show where all other values in the fields are the same, concatenate the names.

e.g.

```
 col 1 col 2 col 3 
    a      1      mary 
    a      1      jane
    a      1      kevin
    b      2      mary
    b      2      jane
    b      2      kevin
    c      3      mary
    c      3      jane
    c      3      kevin
```

output to be:

```
a      1      mary, jane, kevin
b      2      mary, jane, kevin
c      3      mary, jane, kevin
```

I have tried using rtrim but it is not doing anything. I also tried using listagg but I get an error 'Not a group by expression'

All fields are strings and not calculable.

TIA

Comment: you know you have to use `listagg`. can you show your current attempt?

Comment: If you got an error about "not a group by expression" when trying `listagg()` - did you try to add a `GROUP BY` clause? Even more elementary, when you tried `listagg()` and it didn't work, did you use Google (with a search phrase like `Oracle listagg`)? That would have taken you to the Oracle documentation, with an explanation of what this function is, the proper syntax and a few examples. Get in the habit of Googling for Oracle documentation, you will find that to be at least as helpful as this website.

Answer (score 3):

Details [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)

```
select col1, 
       col2, 
       listagg(col3,     -- The aggregated column
               ',')      -- The delimiter
         within group    -- Because this is an aggregated function, needs to be grouped
         (order by Col3) -- We can order the aggregated values
           as Col3       -- And an alias for good measure
from TableA
group by col1, col2
```